# /etc/systemd/logind.conf ignored

Tags: suspend, systemd

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, when I'm setting `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to have:

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
```

It appears to have no effect.

Same happens if I set these to "ignore".

I'm rebooting between attempts.

Why is my `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` ignored? Do I need to do something to enable it? How can I debug this?

Answer (score -1):

You must disable the Xfce4 energy manager to read the settings of the `logind.conf` file. Remember to restart the system every time you modify and save the `logind.conf` file.